# What type of entity is this?

Tags: database, database-design

So I am really confused on trying to get this to 3NF. Is this correct? If it is then what would you call this entity?

[image]

If I would have left the Description in the table, it would be dependent on DonutName, so I had to move it to its own table to put this in 3NF. Correct?

Thanks for any help, just want to make sure I am on the right track. :)

*Edit

Example of the data:
[image]

Comment: Why would the description be dependent on the name and not the ID?

Comment: Agreed. Can you provide samples--better make that "examples"--of what the data looks like?

Comment: I apologize, I see where the confusion is. Lets say for example DonutID "1" is "Chocolate" with a description of "Chocolate Donut". And DonutID "2" is "Sprinkled" with a description of "Sprinkled Donut". So DonutID, Description, and DonutName are always unique and could be the key for each row.

Comment: Here is an example of the data. http://i.imgur.com/F3oYAOI.png

Comment: I meant, if the table was one. Then description *could* be dependent on DonutName therefore it isn't in 3NF correct, since DonutName would not be a PK?

Comment: I don't see a valid reason for moving the Description in another table other than perhaps vertical partitioning but that's a performance question, not a normalization question. If you can have duplicate descriptions for different names, you might add a new Description table and a linktable between them both but for your given sample data, one table fits the bill.

Comment: Would that not break 3NF? Since description could be dependent on another non primary key (Name)? I thought all non-key's could only be dependent on the primary? If there is more then one then you are not in 3NF?

Comment: @Bowhuntr11 - it's been a while since I had to learn this but if I recall correctly, the DonutID's shouldn't be there either when normalizing your data. After normalizing, you should only have natural primary key's. Not an answer to your question *(because I honestly don't know)* but if this is for an exam, by all means: *follow the book*.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I agree with you that DonutID shouldn't even really be in there, but the form I am going off of says that I need to include it, unfortunately. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me your data is

```
Name
Description
UnitPrice
```

A core assumption based on your description: Name is a **candidate** key, in that no two donuts will have the same name.

If Description is also unique within the table, then it too is a candidate key. If it is not unique then it is just an attribute, same as UnitPrice (i.e. two rows in the table could contain the same value).

When you have two candidate keys, you pick one and make it the **primary key**, and all others are **alternate keys**. This in and of itself does not violate third normal form.

Next assumption: DonutId is an identity column – that, or some other device that assigns an (essentially) random integer value to each row. That makes this a **surrogate key** – it’s unique, it can serve as a candidate key (and be “promoted” to primary key), but the data itself has no intrinsic value or meaning (e.g. donut #37 means nothing to the world of donuts) . This would give you three candidate keys, shortly followed by a primary key and two alternate keys. Still seems like third normal form to me. (The other columns would be **natural keys**.)

Now, as far as the academics are concerned, I may be wrong—all these candidate keys may require need to be further broken down to BCNF, fourth normal form, fifth normal form, and whatnot… but given the overall simplicity of the data being modeled, I just don’t think so.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! The extra data on the "assignment" is for a customer. The instructions said "Take this table and make it 2NF." So I take out customer and put it into his own table. Then the instructions say "Now make it 3NF". So I guess I will just put in there that the table already qualifies for 3NF. I hope it works, if not then I know where I should head first to resubmit it :) Thanks again!